# How to merge two MS word documents into alternating lines?

Tags: microsoft-word

For example I have two MS word documents, one for Japanese lyrics, another one for the Japanese written in romaji. (I know how to do this by scripting in Python, but I would like to know a native MS word approach.)

### Document 1:

あなたの指がその胸がその瞳が

眩しくて少し眩暈がする夜もある

それは不意に落ちてきて　あまりにも暖かくて

### Document 2:

anata no yubi ga sono mune ga sono hitomi ga

mabushikute sukoshi memai ga suru yoru mo aru

sore wa fui ni ochite kite  amari nimo atatakakute

### What I want to get

あなたの指がその胸がその瞳が

anata no yubi ga sono mune ga sono hitomi ga

眩しくて少し眩暈がする夜もある

mabushikute sukoshi memai ga suru yoru mo aru

それは不意に落ちてきて　あまりにも暖かくて

sore wa fui ni ochite kite  amari nimo atatakakute

Comment: You could probably do this with a VBA script, but we won't write it for you. If you give it a go and get stuck then ask for help.

Comment: The reason I asked is that I remember I did it without scripting few years back. I just cannot recall how did I do it.

Answer (score 5):

I finally figured it out

### Step 1: Convert both of your documents into tables

Select your text, and click **Convert Text To Table**, a window will pop up. Leave everything default, except the **Separate text at** section.

Depending on your text format, you might want to separate the text differently. For my case, I want to separate it line by line, therefore I clicked **Other** and type in **l**. **l** means line breaks.
[image]

Do the same for the other document.

### Step 2: Create an extra column for your main text

This step to prepare for merging the two text.

[image]

### Step 3: Paste your secondary text to the new column of the main text

Copy the text from your secondary document and then paste it to your main document. Now you should have both text in the same word document occupying two columns.
[image]

### Step 4

Converting table back to text. This time separate text with **Paragraph marks**
[image]

Here we go! Finishing the task without scripting any code!